# Give us an 'Edit & Close' button in the CV queue

Tags: feature-request, edits, review, vote-to-close

When reviewing the Close Votes queue, the current button order often works nicely:

> <kbd>Leave Open</kbd><kbd>Close</kbd><kbd>Edit</kbd><kbd>Skip</kbd>

But there's one problem: The function of the <kbd>**Edit**</kbd> button: Edits the post, then casts an (apparently binding(!)) Leave Open vote - that seems to kick the question out of the queue.

I don't very often use the Edit button, but most of the time I do use it is on posts with glaring problems.

What posts have glaring problems?  Low-quality ones. Often, it is these kinds of posts that need to be closed.

I would propose a checkbox above the Save Edits button - something like:

> Cast a close vote

We could leave this box unchecked by default. When checked, the Save Edits button could also bring up a standard Close dialog - just like normal.